# JavaScript - How to target nested (child) div within a div which was passed using "this"?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change classes of a container div element and few div elements nested within it, when clicked on the container div. I can successfully change the class of container element (case_study_section), but don't know how to target the nested (child) div elements (case_study_images, case_study_image1,..). Please help.

P.S.: I need to add different classes to different child elements. So will hvae to target them separately.

```js
function expandCollapse(case_study_section) {
  var sectionClasses = case_study_section.classList;
  
 var imagesClasses = case_study_section.getElementsByClassName('case_study_images').classList;

  if (sectionClasses.contains("collapsed_section")) {
    sectionClasses.remove("collapsed_section");
    sectionClasses.add("expanded_section");
  } else {
    sectionClasses.remove("expanded_section");
    sectionClasses.add("collapsed_section");
  }
}
```

```css
.case_study_section {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.collapsed_section {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.expanded_section {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="case_study_section collapsed_section" onClick="expandCollapse(this)">

  <div class="case_study_images collapsed_images">

    <div class="case_study_image1">
    </div>

    <div class="case_study_image2">
    </div>

    <div class="case_study_image3">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: He's not asking for jQuery solutions.

Comment: I want to avoid using jQuery, if possible. Any pure JS solution?

Comment: Why do you want to change the classes on descendant elements as well? If you want to format them differently, then you should do that in your CSS, using the class they already have.

Comment: ah np - thought I saw a `$` kicking around xD will remove my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have the parent are looking for some children you can:

```
var elements = case_study_section.querySelectorAll('.case_study_images');

Array.from(elements).forEach(function (child) {
  child.classList.add('a-class');
})
```

Just use a regular css selector.

If you need to add different classes to different children you can:

```
//somehow map the selector to the classes
//here the object key is the selector,
//the value the classes
var map = {
  '.case_study_image1': ['a-class', 'b-class'],
  '.case_study_image2': ['c-class']
};

//iterate over the keys
Object.keys(map).forEach(function (selector) {
      //get the classes
  var classes = map[selector],
      //get the element
      element = case_study_section.querySelector(selector),
      //get the classList
      cl = element.classList;

  //apply all at once
  cl.add.apply(cl, classes);
});
```

Comment: Your solution works. BUT I need to add different classes to different child elements. So need to target them separately. Kindly help me a bit more :)

Comment: Oh.. Maybe, it has to be array because there is always chance of having multiple elements targeted as we are dealing with class. So this works and seems to be the best logical solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `var children = this.getElementsByTagName("div").getElementsByTagName("div")` and then do stuff with the elements returned by that

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`children`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp)

```
  case_study_section.getElementsByClassName('case_study_images')[0].children
```

**Or** [`x.getElementsByClassName()\[0\]`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp)

```
 case_study_section.getElementsByClassName('case_study_images')[0].getElementsByClassName('images classname')[0]
```

```js
function expandCollapse(case_study_section) {
  var sectionClasses = case_study_section.classList;
  
 var imagesClasses = case_study_section.getElementsByClassName('case_study_images').classList;
  
  console.log(case_study_section.getElementsByClassName('case_study_images')[0].children)

  if (sectionClasses.contains("collapsed_section")) {
    sectionClasses.remove("collapsed_section");
    sectionClasses.add("expanded_section");
  } else {
    sectionClasses.remove("expanded_section");
    sectionClasses.add("collapsed_section");
  }
}
```

```css
.case_study_section {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.collapsed_section {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.expanded_section {
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="case_study_section collapsed_section" onClick="expandCollapse(this)">

  <div class="case_study_images collapsed_images">

    <div class="case_study_image1">
    </div>

    <div class="case_study_image2">
    </div>

    <div class="case_study_image3">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```